# transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to utilize transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: but in uiview class reference this point is confusing me. What it means?

> This method modifies the views in their view hierarchy only. It does
>   not modify your application’s view controllers in any way. For
>   example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a
>   view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view
>   controller appropriately to handle the change.

Please view the sample project https://anonfiles.com/file/521cbb41b086eae987fe27eb98278aba

In this project I just called `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` and everything is working fine and did nothing what is mentioned in the above point.

Comment: Did you change a root view or a subview of the root view? And did you try to use the view controller afterwards?

Comment: @Wain Sorry I didn't get your point? Please download and view the sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more likely asking for an explanation of Apple's documentation than a specific question, if I understand your posting correctly.

Nevertheless I'll give you this explanation and I hope, it will help you:

You write:

> Everything is working fine..

and that is, because you a doing well here!

According to the **MVC** design pattern (Model-View-Controller), you are using the classes UIViewController (the "C") and UIView (the "V") in your code.

A view contains the visual representation of objects (like labels, buttons, subviews, ...) without an logic for their behavior.

A viewcontroller provides the logic, e. g. IBAction methods and any other methods that you may implement.

Each UIViewController has its own "view" property containing the view, whose behavior the controller does manage. This view normally contains additional views, e. g. labels, images and buttons. They are subviews and are stored in the view's "subviews" array property. Btw, each view has such a subviews property - that is, how we can implement complex view hierarchies.

In your situation (multiple subviews that are managed by one common viewcontroller), the method

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

hides "fromView" and unhides "toView" with the support of animations. It is a **transition between to views**. The paragraph from the documentation shall prepare you as a developer, that this method only manages the change of the visual representation and does not provide additional "services" for your view controller for the further management for the participating views.

That means, that you have to manage e. g. the state of the views (which view actually provides interaction for the user) by your own code. **It seems to me, that you have managed this well!**

**In a wider scope**, iOS supports UIViewController container as well - they can contain child view controllers (which again contain their view with its subviews). In such an architecture, there is another transition method from the SDK,

```
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

which allows you to implement **transitions** not between two views, but **between two view controllers**.

I hope this is not too much text and helps to make things clearer for you.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed reply, its very useful, please clear this also that I am transitioning between views of two different viewcontrollers self.svc = [[secondVC alloc]init];
    
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.svc.view...

Comment: and did nothing as apple said in doc "it is your responsibility to update the view controller appropriately to handle the change." But secondviewcontroller working fine.

Comment: what apple means here "For example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view controller appropriately to handle the change."

Comment: @S.J I've tested your code. You are right, that your view in controller2 appears. But from this point, you are lost (in iOS space *g*) Neither controller1 nor controller2 from now on really is in place. Please test by yourself: overwrite the "viewWillLayoutSubviews" method in both of your viewControllers and let them NSLog "controller1"/"controller2" and run your app. Play with the autorotation and you will see: it happens in controller1 as expected. After the transition, your controller2 doesn't answer anymore. That said, you'll have to change your architecture according to the documentation.

Comment: You are correct after transitionfromview to secondVC and rotating the device, secondvc do not respond.

Comment: means its absolutely wrong to display the view of another viewcontroller using transitionfromview? but why I didnt get any error or why apple didnt prevent doing this?

Comment: I want to switch from this firstVC to secondVC what is the proper way to do it? But without UINavigationController, UITabBarController, present view controller modally, add as subview.

Comment: I would like to invite you on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657719/please-clear-some-confusions-regarding-uiviewcontroller