# Please clear some confusions regarding UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Please clear some confusions regarding `UIViewController`

I found this article `Abusing UIViewController` and here are the links [link1](http://littlehales.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) & [link2](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/)

and summarised points

This is author's (and Apple’s) advice In a nutshell:

1. One (and only one) view controller should be responsible for a whole hierarchy (or screenful) of UIViews.
2. Mostly, you should only use one view controller per screen. Essentially the `rootViewController` of the current `UIWindow` should be the only `UIViewController` with a visible view.
3. Each different screen should have a different view controller i.e. one controller should not control more than one screen.
4. You should NOT nest custom `UIViewControllers` within a view hierarchy.
5. If more than one `UIViewController` hangs off the application’s `UIWindow`, only one of these will get the messages for changes in orientation. The other(s) will NOT get these messages.
6. Nested `UIViewControllers` are not guaranteed, or likely, to receive messages for changes in orientation or lifecycle messages such as `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidDisappear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` even though they inherit from `UIViewController`. Only the topmost `UIViewController` is certain to get these messages.

**Please clear point number 2 and 3**
because when we use `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` we use multiple subclasses of `UIViewController`. And ios device has only one screen.....

This article [Abusing UIViewController](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) highlight apple suggestion

> Note: If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas
>   and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom
>   objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects
>   to manage each subarea. Then use a single view controller object to
>   manage the generic controller objects.

and in [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1) under heading of `Coordinating Efforts Between View Controllers` apple saying

> Few iOS apps show only a single screenful of content. Instead, they
>   show some content when first launched and then show and hide other
>   content in response to user actions. These transitions provide a
>   single unified user interface that display a lot of content, just not
>   all at once.....

My requirement is **NOT** to use any container or modal or popover, I want to do manual management, I have two view controllers `VC1` & `VC2`. `VC1` is the root view controller now I want to switch/transit/move to `VC2` what should I do?

1. `VC1` should be the only subclass of `UIViewController` and `VC2` should be the subclass of `NSObject` to manage a particular view in `VC1` hierarchy?(the show hide thing by apple doc).
2. `VC2` can also be the subclass of `UIViewController`, I just remove `VC1` from root view and add `VC2` as root view?

or what is the correct way?

Comment: These are important general questions one has to figure out to develop the architecture of an app. You could write a whole book about such basic topics. Not to forget, that Apple leverages the SDK over time and answers from yesterday aren't always the answers for today's or tomorrow's issues. I develop own container view controllers in a situation, when I want to use the child view controllers not only in the container, but also as fully functional view controllers without a parent container view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Container view controllers (like UINavigationController) allow working around the one-VC-per-screen rule.  Since iOS 5, developers have been able and allowed to write our own container controllers (which aren't actually much different from normal VCs).  Generally this means that writing non-VC controller objects is less necessary than it used to be.

In your situation, where you want to replace the root view controller, your option 2 makes more sense.  Use VCs where you can, and non-VC controller objects only when you can't. Since you're replacing the whole screen's content, just switching the `UIWindow rootViewController` makes the most sense (edit: alternately, many devs would just use a navigation controller to present the second view, because it's simple and convenient).

Comment: Thanks for replying, Sorry I didn't get this point "Container view controllers (like UINavigationController) allow working around the one-VC-per-screen rule", but idevices has only one screen. For learning purpose please consider only ios4 is available we dont have custom container OR how its all done before ios5?

Comment: Pre-iOS5, you have three Apple-provided container VCs: Navigation controllers, tab controllers, and (on iPad only) split-view controllers.  If you need to have multiple controllers for on-screen views, and the method by which you want to display them doesn't fit the patterns of the provided container VCs, you would want to be careful to write non-VC controller classes for all but one of the visible parts.

Comment: I dont want to show any multiple view controllers at a time on screen, I totally do want to use modal, popover or container.